# Can I give a link in standard message box in SAP UI5?

Tags: javascript, xml, hyperlink, sapui5, messagebox

Is it possible to give a link instead of a message in standard message box in sap ui5? I want to navigate to another view on the click of that link. Is it possible to achieve without creating a new fragment and adding something in the standard message box?

Comment: Is it acceptable that the navigation happens when the user clicks on one of the buttons?

Comment: I know the solution with the button, but i need to navigate on click of the link

Answer (score 0):

The sap.m.MessageBox does not allow links, but the use of custom actions. Just take a look at the sample [Error with custom action](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.MessageBox/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageBox). Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution:

```
if (!this.oSuccessMessageDialog) {
    this.oSuccessMessageDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
        type: sap.m.DialogType.Message,
        title: "Success",
        state: sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success,
        content: [
            new sap.m.Text({ text: "Click on\u00a0" }),
            new sap.m.Link({
                text: "this",
                emphasized: true,
                press: <your_handler>
            }),
            new sap.m.Text({ text: "\u00a0Link." })
        ],
        beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
            type: sap.m.ButtonType.Emphasized,
            text: "OK",
            press: function () {
                this.oSuccessMessageDialog.close();
            }.bind(this)
        })
    });
}
this.oSuccessMessageDialog.open();
```